# Python argparse: "Dry run" flag that disable other flags using

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I have the following helper function for parsing arguments using `argparse`:

```py
def get_cli_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='Xtrayce')
    parser.add_argument(
        "-o", "--output",
        default=get_default_output_path(),
        help="Supply an output path.",
        type=argparse.FileType('wb'),
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-d", "--dry",
        help="Don't save a file with the output.",
        action="store_true",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-s", "--standard",
        help="Also scan standard library and modules.",
        action="store_true",
    )
```

I want that whenever the user specify the `--dry` flag, no file will be created from the `--output` parameter.

What is the best way to "cancel" the file creation when the user specifies `--dry`, while still using `default=` and `type=argparse.FileType("wb")`?

Comment: as a sidenote, the posix unspoken convention for `--dry-run` shorthand is `-n`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this via the default `ArgumentParser` as the file will be created already during the parsing of the arguments.

You can either change the type of `--output` to a string and add a check before writing:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='Xtrayce')
parser.add_argument(
    "-o", "--output",
    default=get_default_output_path(),
    help="Supply an output path.",
)
parser.add_argument(
    "-d", "--dry",
    help="Don't save a file with the output.",
    action="store_true",
)

if not args.dry:
    with open(args.output, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(...)
```

Or instead of using a `--dry` parameter, you could provide `-` as the `--output` argument, which will write to `sys.stdout` instead of a file.

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.FileType):

> FileType objects understand the pseudo-argument '-' and automatically
>   convert this into `sys.stdin` for readable `FileType` objects and
>   `sys.stdout` for writable `FileType` objects:
>
> ````
> parser.add_argument('infile', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
> parser.parse_args(['-']) Namespace(infile=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' encoding='UTF-8'>)```
> ````